# Ruby match groups of JavaScript variables

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to extract variable names from this scratch of code:

```
var a,b,c,  foo = "Test this is string";
```

I'd like the match result to contain a,b,c and foo and value optionally.
I am able to split the string by a comma but I wonder if there's a way for this directly from the regex.

```
var\s+(.+)\s*,?\s*=.+;
```

You can test this out at http://rubular.com/
It shows me `a,b,c,foo` part but I'd like it to output in match groups like that:

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more capturing groups to capture all the parts of the string the way you want:

```
var\s+(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),\s*(\w+)\s*=.+;
```

Output of the [demo](http://rubular.com/r/CExFtx16gP):

```
1.  a
2.  b
3.  c
4.  foo
```

Mind that if there is a non-specified number of arguments, this will not work.

As an alternative, use a regex with `\G` that forces consecutive matches:

```
(?:var\s+|(?<!^)\G)[,\s]*(\w+)
```

Output of [another demo](http://rubular.com/r/OXvrq2FO6M):

```
Match 1
1.  a
Match 2
1.  b
Match 3
1.  c
Match 4
1.  foo
```

Comment: I like the second solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, it is safer: it checks if there is `var `, and then matches each sequence of alphanumerics separated with `,` and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the below lookaround based regex.

```
string.scan(/(?<=[\s,])\w+(?=,?[^="']*=)/)
```

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/J0PO3bX1xC)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know ?= operator before